# How to trigger release pipeline when artifacts are generated from main code not from shelveset code in TFS 2017?

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, azure-devops, continuous-deployment

I am working on TFS 2017 and using release pipeline feature.

I have enabled "Continuous Deployment" and as soon as a new artifact version is available it trigger the release pipeline irrespective of whether it is generated by shelveset or by main code but I need to trigger only when the artifact is generated by main code not by shelveset .

Please Note - I cannot write ne(variables['Build.Reason'],'Shelveset') in publish task of Build definition because the manual tester needs artifacts.

Any help is appreciated

Thanks

Comment: Why do the manual testers need artifacts for something generated from a shelveset? Shelvesets should be used only for short-term storage and validation of changes prior to committing them. In any other case, make a new branch.

Comment: Because some time manual tester wants to test the changes but I don't want to run automation test cases on that.

Answer (score 1):

The following is a good approach to take in TFS, using the workflow and task-based approach. Basically, you are defining a tag when that is automatically assigned to a build when a build successfully completes based on certain conditions, in the below example only if a build is scheduled, but you can customize the condition to run on all build reasons except shelveset builds too if you want.

At the end of your Build Definition create a new task for "PowerShell Script" and in the Inline Script put in the following:

Write-Host "##vso[build.addbuildtag]TriggerRelease"

Further down go to the Control Options and change the "Run this Task" to custom tasks and put the following: More variables can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=vsts), this is the page that details the different build.reason variables that are accessible. The conditions and how to use them can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/conditions?view=vsts&tabs=yaml)

and(succeeded(), in(variables['Build.Reason'], 'Schedule'))